# Boolean Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I am facing a little problem here. 
I have fetch the data from data using following code,

```
class CreateGrounddetails < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :grounddetails do |t|
   t.string :name
   t.datetime :working_hours
   t.string :address
   t.string :contact_no
   t.string :email
   t.integer :number_of_grounds
   t.text :description
   t.boolean :featured_ground #Featured  
   t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end
```

I have a boolean value which stored in the field "featured_ground", now I want to fetch only the data which has "TRUE" value for "featured_ground".
How can I achieve that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i wanna feature ground which is true for certain time period..how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do

```
Grounddetail.where(featured_ground: true)
```

Which gives you the expected records.

Comment: thanks alot... i was so frustrated for how to do this..thanks :)

Comment: hey thanks alot for this answer..now i wanna feature ground which is true for certain time period ..how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
Grounddetail.where(featured_ground: true)
```

OR

```
Grounddetail.where(:featured_ground => true)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10943334)

Comment: If this is not an answer then what is it?

Comment: Your answer was flagged as "too short", actually is less more than a comment. I suggest you to add more details to let users understand "why" it could be a good one or maybe the best one. Leting users to understand reasons help them in other similar situations.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do it assuming your model will be named `Grounddetail`.

```
Grounddetail.where(:featured_ground => true)
```

You can check the sql generated by using

```
Grounddetail.where(:featured_ground => true).to_sql
```